# How do I use variable from another command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently making an economy system for my discord bot, and while working on one of its features, I got stuck.
My bot should be able to allow the user to exchange the main currency (money) for ducks.
The gimmick of the ducks is that their price will fluctuate every hour/day.

Here's my code for changing the value of the ducks:

```
 async def duckvalue(self, ctx):
  baseprice = 10000
  while True:
    newprice = baseprice + random.randint(-5000, 5000)
    baseprice = newprice
    if baseprice < 0:
      baseprice = 1000
```

It simply constantly changes the price of ducks by a random number. If I add `await ctx.send(f"{baseprice}")`, This is what the output looks like:

```
13673
17867
19144
16878
13936
```

This command works perfectly. My problem lies with using this price changer command in other commands.
Here is my duck buying command:

```
@commands.command()
async def buyducks(self, ctx, *, amount = None):

  await self.open_account(ctx.author)

  users = await self.get_bank_data()

  user = ctx.author

  duckprice = self.baseprice

  totalprice = int(duckprice) * int(amount)

  if amount == None:
    await ctx.send("You must specify the amount of ducks you want to buy.")
  elif users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] < totalprice:
    await ctx.send("You don't have enough money to buy this amount of ducks.")
  else:
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] -= totalprice
    users[str(user.id)]["ducks"] += int(amount)

    with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users,f)
```

All that really matters in this block of code is the line where I try to use the `baseprice` variable from my other command. I tried putting `self.` in front of baseprice, but it didn't work.

So, maybe somebody can help me. Is there a way I can plug my price changer into my buy ducks command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried putting `self.` in front of baseprice, but it didn't work.' -- *why?* If you use `self.baseprice` everywhere you'll be able to access that variable from another function.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I added self. to all mentions of baseprice but I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Economy' object has no attribute 'baseprice'`

Answer (score 1):

`self.baseprice` isn't working because in `duckvalue` you haven't initialized baseprice as a class variable. Instead it is just a local variable accessible only in the function scope.

You should do it like this -

```
 async def duckvalue(self, ctx):
  self.baseprice = 10000
  while True:
    newprice = self.baseprice + random.randint(-5000, 5000)
    self.baseprice = newprice
    if self.baseprice < 0:
      self.baseprice = 1000
```

And for the error you mentioned in the comments, you should initialize baseprice as a class variable in the starting like this -

```
class Economy:
    baseprice = 0
```

and then it will be accessible as `self.baseprice`

Comment: At first, this seems to work, but after using it I realized that baseprice stays at 0 (or whatever int I give it when declaring it ) therefore the price is always 0. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I don't have much experience with making discord bots but I think that the case might be that the class is being initialized every time a command is being issued